# GetApplicablePromotions is returning promotions with wrong product

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I have created a gift purchase promotion particular items(like on purchase 5 X soaps get 10% discount)  and using  GetApplicablePromotionNames droplet for displaying those promotions on the items. GetApplicablePromotionNames is returning this promotion for the correct item but not validating pmd rules which has been configured with some customize property.I was validating channel of order should be STORE but for the product promotion displaying for channel=WEB as well.

[image]

Comment: What is the Order Repository definition for Channel in the order repository xml file? Also which version of Oracle Commerce?

Comment: Thanks @bated for your reply.Order channel has configured as String in order repository xml.Using ATG 10.1.2 version.

Comment: Can you please include the actual definition in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have encountered a known issue with version 10.1.2 with the `EverythingQualifierService`.  The workaround is as follows:

> Reconfigure the filters property of the EverythingQualifiesService.properties file to use the EverythingQualifiesService instead of the QualifierService.

There are a number of other known issues with promotions and the full list can be found with [Oracle Commerce 10.1.2 Release Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36434_01/ReleaseNotes.10-1-2/MerchReleaseNotes/html/s0000coremerchandising01.html).

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.Am using only EverythingQualifiesService for the filters property.But issues not yet resolved- bated

Comment: Did you look at all the known issues with promotions which is in the link to the release notes?